# Spark - Java - Create Parquet/Avro Without Using Dataframes of Spark SQL

Tags: java, apache-spark, avro, parquet

I want to get output of a Spark application(which we only use core Spark and people working on the project do not want to change it to Spark SQL) as Parquet or Avro files.

When I look for these two file types, I couldn't find any example without DataFrames, or in general Spark SQL. Can I achieve this without using SparkSQL?

My data is tabular, it has columns but in the processing, all data will be used, not a single column. It's columns are decided at runtime, so there is no "name,ID,adress" kinda generic columns. It looks like this:

```
No f1       f2       f3       ...
1, 123.456, 123.457, 123.458, ...
2, 123.789, 123.790, 123.791, ...
...
```

Comment: Could you please elaborate what do you want to achieve

Comment: My output is going large as I use more input data. Currently, it is 3.5Gb. It should be smaller in size(which I can achieve with Snappy compression), but they also ask me if there is another output type which can be used to decrease the size, read/write time etc. Currently it is just a human-readeble text file.

Comment: Ok so if you want to save your output in Avro without dataframe and spark sql then you can use rdd

Comment: Rdd.toDF().write.parquet(filepath)

Comment: Okay, which means anyway I need to use SparkSQL. At least only at the end. Because, I can't see a toDF() method for my Pair and normal JavaRDD's.

Comment: See my answer below. Use createdataframeapi

Comment: So why such a principled question? The APIs are what they are ...

Comment: Because I don't own the project, they don't want to change everything from the beginning and we have limited time.

Answer (score 1):

You can’t save an rdd in parquet without converting it to dataframe. Rdd does not have schema but parquet file is in columnar format which needs schema, so we need to convert it to dataframe.

You can use createdataframe api

Answer (score 0):

I tried this and it works like a champ...

```
public class ParquetHelper{

    static ParquetWriter<GenericData.Record> writer = null;
    private static Schema schema;

    public ParquetHelper(Schema schema, String pathName){

        try {
            Path path = new Path(pathName);
            writer = AvroParquetWriter.
                    <GenericData.Record>builder(path)
                    .withRowGroupSize(ParquetWriter.DEFAULT_BLOCK_SIZE)
                    .withPageSize(ParquetWriter.DEFAULT_PAGE_SIZE)
                    .withSchema(schema)
                    .withConf(new Configuration())
                    .withCompressionCodec(CompressionCodecName.SNAPPY)
                    .withValidation(true)
                    .withDictionaryEncoding(false)
                    .build();
            this.schema = schema;
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

     /*
     * 
     */
    public static void writeToParquet(JavaRDD<Record> empRDDRecords) throws IOException {

        empRDDRecords.foreach(record -> {
            if(null != record && new RecordValidator().validate(record, schema).isEmpty()){
                writeToParquet(record);
            }// TODO collect bad records here
        });

        writer.close();
    }

}
```